# Find External Key of Data Extension from JourneyID

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, ssjs, automationstudio

Can we find the External Key of Data Extension related to the Journey Builder using JourneyID? Is this possible to be done by SSJS or SQL?

Comment: I imagine through rest api you can get the DE and then use ssjs to get the external key???

Comment: Hey, Ben.  In the future, please include in your question what you've tried and where you're stuck.  You'll find the effort in the questions results in effort in the responses.  A hearty hat-tip to [shd.lux](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/79899/shd-lux) who took a good chunk of time to answer so thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can via the REST API and WSProxy.

First you would need to find the journey data via `GET /interaction/v1/interactions` ([SFMC doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postCreateInteraction.htm)) and grab the `triggers`. Within the `triggers` you can find the `event definitions` which you can use to find the `ObjectId` of the trigger `Data Extension` by calling the endpoint `GET /interaction/v1/eventDefinitions/{id}` ([SFMC doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm#detail_getEventDefinition)).

As soon as you have the `ObjectId` of the associated `Data Extension` you can use `WSProxy` ([gortonington blog's get you started](https://gortonington.com/sfmc-server-side-javascript-5-wsproxy/)) to retrieve all informations about this `Data Extension`.

Sounds complicated?

I have written a quick solution for you which should get you what you need. Please note, that anything in regards of `Server-2-Server` REST API integration and token generation has been left out of the code. Here are great articles [by Ivan Razine](https://ampscript.xyz/?s=rest) to get you started on this one as well.

Furthermore, the code makes many assumptions and ignores if a journey has been stopped.

**Code:**

```js
    <script runat="server">
        Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.5");

        try {

            var restBaseURI = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/',
                // a SFMC access token
                token = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjQiLCJ2ZXIixxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

            var journeyId = 'DDD4FDB8-34F7-4133-9406-EE316052CE2D',
                journeyVersion = 13;


            // get journey data by id
            var journeyData = getJourneyByID(journeyId,null,journeyVersion),
                journeyTriggerEventDefinitionId = journeyData.triggers[0].metaData.eventDefinitionId;

            if (journeyTriggerEventDefinitionId) {

                // get triggered EventDefinition data
                var journeyEventDefinition = getJourneyEventDefinitions(journeyTriggerEventDefinitionId),
                    journeyTriggerDataExtensionObjectId = journeyEventDefinition.dataExtensionId;

                // get Data Extension Key based on object id
                if (journeyTriggerDataExtensionObjectId) {

                    var dataExtension = retrieveDataExtensionByObjectId(journeyTriggerDataExtensionObjectId);

                    Write(dataExtension.Name);
                    Write(dataExtension.CustomerKey);
                }
            }

        } catch(e) {
            Write(Stringify(e))
        }



         /**
         * Retrieves a single journey by ID or key.
         *
         * To call this resource, assign your API Integration the Automation | Interactions | Read scope.
         *
         * @param   {string}    id                  ID of version 1 of the journey in the form of a GUID (UUID).
         *                                          Required if not using a key.
         * @param   {string}    key                 The key of the journey. Required if not using ID. 
         *                                          Prefix the parameter with key:. For example: key:{key}.
         * @param   {number}    [versionNumber]     Version number of the journey to retrieve. If not provided, 
         *                                          version 1 is returned.
         * @param   {string}    [extras]            A list of additional data to fetch. Available values are: 
         *                                          all, activities, outcomes and stats. Default is 'all'.
         *
         * @returns {object}
         *
         * @see {link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm#detail_getInteractionById|getInteractionById}
         *
         * @example
         * // using id
         * var resp = getJourneyByID('DDD4HDX8-34F7-4143-9406-EE916052CEAD');
         * 
         * // using key
         * var resp = getJourneyByID(null,'key:DDD4HDX8-34F7-4143-9406-EE916052CEAD');
         * 
         */
        function getJourneyByID(id,key,versionNumber,extras) {
            var config = {
                    url: restBaseURI + "interaction/v1/interactions/",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    header: {
                        Authorization: "Bearer " + token
                    }
                };

            if (!id && !key ) {
                throw '(getJourneyByID)\n\tRequired Parameter missing';
            }

            config.url += (id)?id:key;
            config.url += (versionNumber)?"?versionNumber="+versionNumber:'?versionNumber=1';
            config.url += (extras)?"&extras="+extras:'&extras=all';
            
            var req = httpRequest('GET',config.url, config.contentType, null, config.header);

            if (req.status == 200) {
                return req.content;
            } else {
                throw '(getJourneyByID)\n\tRetrieve Journey failed';
            }

        }


         /**
         * Retrieves an individual event definition by ID or key.
         *
         * @param   {string}    id                  ID of version 1 of the journey in the form of a GUID (UUID).
         *                                          Required if not using a key.
         * @param   {string}    key                 The key of the journey. Required if not using ID. 
         *
         * @returns {object}
         *
         * @see {link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm#detail_getEventDefinition|getInteractionById}
         *
         * @example
         * // using id
         * var resp = rest.getJourneyEventDefinitions('DDD4HDX8-34F7-4143-9406-EE916052CEAD');
         * 
         * // using key
         * var resp = rest.getJourneyEventDefinitions(null,'key:DDD4HDX8-34F7-4143-9406-EE916052CEAD');
         * 
         */
        function getJourneyEventDefinitions(id,key) {
            var config = {
                    url: restBaseURI + "interaction/v1/eventDefinitions/",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    header: {
                        Authorization: "Bearer " + token
                    }
                };

            if (!id && !key ) {
                throw '(getJourneyEventDefinitions)\n\tError: Required Parameter missing';
            }

            config.url += (id)?id:key;
            
            var req = httpRequest('GET',config.url, config.contentType, null, config.header);

            if (req.status == 200) {
                return req.content;
            } else {
                throw '(getJourneyEventDefinitions)\n\tError: Retrieve Journey failed';
            }

        }

        /**
         * Retrieve informations about a single DataExtension based on the object id.
         * 
         * @param {string}  objectId  The internal identifier for the DataExtension.
         *
         * @returns {object} Result set of the request.
         *
         */
        function retrieveDataExtensionByObjectId(objectId) {
            var cols = retrievableCols('DataExtension'),
                property = ['Name','CustomerKey'],
                req = {};

            var req = prox.retrieve("DataExtension", cols, { 
                Property: 'ObjectId', 
                SimpleOperator: "equals", 
                Value: objectId
            });

            if( req.Status == 'OK' && req.Results.length > 0 ) {
                return req.Results[0];
            }
            throw '(retrieveDataExtensionByObjectId)\n\tError: Cannot find DataExtension with ObjectId: '+objectId;
        }


        /** 
         * Retrieves all retrievable columns for the given object.
         * 
         * @param {string} objectType The SFMC Object to retrieve cols from.
         *
         * @returns {array} A list of al retrievable columns.
         *
         * @example
         * // retrieve cols for DataExtension
         * var cols = retrievableCols('DataExtension');
         *
         * @see {@link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getting_the_fields_available_for_retrieval.htm|Get the Fields Available for Retrieval}
         */
        function retrievableCols(objectType) {
            var cols = [];
            
            var req = prox.describe(objectType);
            var props = req.Results[0].Properties;
            if( props.length > 0 ) {
                for(var i=0; i<props.length; i++) {
                    if( props[i].IsRetrievable ) {
                        cols.push(props[i].Name);
                    }
                }
            }
            return cols;
        }


        /**
         * Perform an HTTP request allowing the usage of API methods.
         *
         * @param {string} method           The method to use e.g: POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, and DELETE
         * @param {string} url              The url to send the request to
         * @param {string} [contentType]    The contentType to use e.g: application/json
         * @param {object} [payload]        A payload for the request body
         * @param {object} [header]         Header values as key value pair
         *
         * @returns {object} Result of the request
         */
        function httpRequest(method,url,contentType,payload,header) {
            var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(url);
            req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
            req.retries = 2;
            req.continueOnError = true;
            req.method = method;
            for( var k in header ) {
                req.setHeader(k, header[k]);
            }
            if(typeof contentType !== 'undefined' && contentType !== null) { req.contentType = contentType; }
            if(typeof payload !== 'undefined' && payload !== null) { req.postData = Platform.Function.Stringify(payload); }

            try {
                var res = req.send();

                return {
                    status: Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(res.statusCode)),
                    content: Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(res.content))
                };

            } catch(e) {
                return {
                    status: '500',
                    content: e
                };
            }
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: hi, I got the req.status == 401, do you have any suggestions? @shd.lux

Comment: even I refresh the token and put the re-generated token, I still get error 401 @shd.lux

Comment: 401 Unauthorized is specifically for use when authentication is possible but has failed or not yet been provided. Your token seem not to authenticate correctly. Review your Server-2-Sever application and credentials as well and validate the token against your instance